# Replace in string selected with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have quite large txt file and I want to use replace in string selected with regex.

File is filled with multiple lines that look like this:

```
...||date|14.02.2010||interest|games and books||options|opt1, opt2 and opt3||age|24||...
```

and now in `|options|opt1, opt2 and opt3|` I want to change `and` to `,` so it looks like `|options|opt1, opt2, opt3|`

I think this should work like this:

1. select string with regex, ex. `\|options\|(.*?)\|`
2. now something like this: replace `and` with `,` in `$1`

and repeat multiple times.

How can I do that in PHP? I hope it's clearly enough.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: he wants a program edit: not anymore

Comment: I think it might not be such a program, so I edited the question. Now I want do this in PHP ;) Remember that I have to do it on a txt file.

Comment: actually you could do it with programs like *grep* and *sed*

Comment: Why php? sed is much better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$str = '...||date|14.02.2010||interest|games and books||options|opt1, opt2 and opt3||age|24||...';

$str = preg_replace('/(\|options\|[^|]*) and/', "$1,", $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
...||date|14.02.2010||interest|games and books||options|opt1, opt2, opt3||age|24||...
```

Comment: This would mangle ...||date|14.02.2010||options|opt1, opt2, opt3||interest|games and books||age|24||...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str= preg_replace('/(\|options\|[^|]+) and /', '\1,', $str);
```

Comment: You're dropping everything you matched.

Comment: nope, it was a look behind! but look behinds must have a fixed length, so I restored my previous solution